# ¿Por qué desaparece un elemento html cuando ocupo jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Buen día. Tengo un problema a la hora de realizar un ejercicio con Jquery.

En mi HTML tengo un div que contiene una lista como tipo menú:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#M1").toggle(function(){
        $("#submenu1").append('<p>Prueba</p>');
    }, function(){
        $("#submenu1").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="M1"><a href="#">Menu Principal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Secundario</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Terceario</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="submenu1">
  
</div>
```

Y cuando ejecuto esto en el navegador, desaparece el elemento li con id M1...

No se a que se deba. Si alguien pudiera orientarme en esto se lo agradeceria mucho. Soy nuevo en esto de la programacion con JavaScript.

Comment: Pues la pregunta dice: **por qué desaparece**? Porque tienes un **hide** en tu document.Ready...

Comment: Si, pero tenia entendido que la funcion toggle espera dos argumentos, el primero que es como ON y el segundo OFF, por eso he colocado el hide(), para que a la hora de dar un segundo click, me desaparezca el menu

Comment: qué comportamiento quiere que tenga al final tu código? qué intentas resolver o hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta hacerlo de esta manera, prueba dando clic a los dos primeros items de la lista:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#M1").toggle(function(){
        $("#submenu1").show();
    }, function(){
        $("#submenu1").hide();
    });
});

//Si lo que quieres es que al presionar el item aparezca y desaparezca el submenú, puedes hacerlo así, ten en cuenta que puse el evento en el segundo item (Menu Secundario)

$("#M2").click(function(){
    $("#submenu1").toggle()
});

//La ventaja de este segundo bloque es que funciona con JQuery 3.3.1
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="M1"><a href="#">Menu Principal</a></li>
        <li id="M2"><a href="#">Menu Secundario</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Terceario</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="submenu1" style="display:none">
  <p>Prueba</p>
</div>
```

Ojalá sea lo que buscas. Cabe mencionar que aquí he usado JQuery 1.8.1 para que funcione, ya que el evento toggle que quieres usar está depreciado en las nuevas versiones, [aquí más información](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), el segundo toggle que he usado es solo una animación nativa de JQuery y sí es permitida en las nuevas versiones.

Comment: Lo he hecho y me ha funcionando!! Muchas gracias Amigo!! Te lo agradezco.

Answer (score 3):

La función `toggle()` quedó obsoleta en la versión 1.8 y removida en la 1.9, por lo tanto, debes de usar versiones anteriores a la 1.8 para usarla.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#M1").toggle(function(){
        $("#submenu1").append('<p>Prueba</p>');
    }, function(){
        $("#submenu1").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="M1"><a href="#">Menu Principal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Secundario</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Terceario</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="submenu1">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por esa aclaración. No sabia que ya la función toggle() habia quedado obsoleta con nuevas versiones de Jquery.